# SharePoint 2013 - Document Sets Not Working

Tags: libraries

I have created several document libraries in different locations on
an established SharePoint 2013 Site Collection in which I have added the
document set content type. I cannot create a document set in any of them
without errors. When I create a document set from the Files tab on the ribbon, I get the error, "Sorry, something went wrong / File Not Found." This happens in
all document libraries when creating a document set.

The document set actually does get created. However, I also can't open the
document sets; I get the same error.

SharePoint seems to be looking for 
/XXXX/Forms/Document%20Set/docsethomepage.aspx. I can see that
file in SharePoint Designer, but if I try to preview it in the browser, the
same error message appears.

Can anyone assist with this please?

Answer (score 0):

this could be a problem with layouts or feature files either missing or not able to refer correctly.

try the below options:

1. deactivate and reactivate the document sets feature for the site collection and see if it works.
2. if the above step doesnt work, try running the config wizard and see it can fix the files in the layouts.